# How to transition between two SVG images?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have a div with a background image set to an SVG image. I need to transition between two SVG images, how would I accomplish this? I am referring to CSS 3 transitions, but other solutions are also welcome.

Comment: CSS3 does not have **transitions** . It has **properties** that when manipulated with Javascript over period of time can cause elements to disappear/move.

Comment: @Yi Jiang - http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-transitions/

Comment: @patrick Thanks! Had a brilliant "I didn't know that!" moment!

Answer (score 0):

It could probably be done with jQuery. Use two divs, one visible, and the other hidden. Then:

```
$("#transition_from_div").hide('fast');
$("#transition_to_div").show('fast');
```

All this is doing is using JavaScript to animate the each div's CSS properties.